# Как сделать контестное меню для QTableWidget в QT5.10.0

Tags: c++, qt5

коллеги! Есть следующий вопрос.

Приложение содержит, кроме всего прочего, несколько таблиц `QTableWidget`. Для каждой таблицы надо создать контекстное меню для правой кнопки мыши.

Меню в общем единообразно: вставить, удалить, добавить строку в таблицу.

Нужен пример кода, поскольку то, что я нашёл либо не то, либо не работает.

Окно программы разумеется сделано с помощью дизайнера форм. Пример C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\Examples\Qt-5.10.0\widgets\mainwindows\menus как-то не помог, он ведь создаёт контекстное меню на всё окно, а не только на таблицы.

Прошу сильно не пинать, я на QT перешёл только 2 мес. назад.

Comment: Что именно вы нашли? Чем вас не устраивает `customContextMenuRequested()` или `addAction()`?

Comment: Что-то у меня не получилось сделать, чтобы сигнал customContextMenuRequested() отправлялся по клику ПКМ из таблицы QTableWidget

Comment: Получилось не так как хотелось. customContextMenuRequested() приводит к тому, что контекстное меню выскакивает везде на форме, а не только в пределах таблиц QTableWidget, а на попытку ограничения такого вида: TableWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)) среда сообщает, что нет такого сигнала

Comment: Странно. сигнал `customContextMenuRequested()` объявлен в `QWidget`, от которого наследуется в том числе и `QTableWidget`. Выложите, пожалуйста, как вы подключали слот напрямую к таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто, разве что такой вариант будет реагировать и на лкм и на пкм.

```
QObject::connect(tableWidget, &QTableWidget::Clicked, this, [this] {
    QMenu menu;
    auto infoA = menu.addAction("Обновить");
    QObject::connect(infoA, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]() {
        Update();
    });
    menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
});
```

Для реагирования только на правую кнопку, надо будет установить фильтр событий методом `installEventFilter` и по нажатию клавиши определять, была ли это пкм

Comment: Странно, но у меня почему-то реагирует только на ЛКМ

Comment: Я немного спутал сигналы, там customContextMenuRequested нужен. И installEventFilter не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Получилось добиться желаемой работы программы. 
Пример программы, которая содержит две таблицы QTableWidget и обе редактируются с помощью контекстного меню

Вот код примера:
Заголовочный файл:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableWidget>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void CreateTable(void);
private slots:
    void appendTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table);
    void insertTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table);
    void deleteTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table);

    void on_tableWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Файл реализации mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ccombodelegate.h"
#include "spinboxdelegate.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    CreateTable();

    this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(this, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(on_tableWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)));

    QString message = tr("A context menu is available by right-clicking");
    statusBar()->showMessage(message);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

#define HEADER_NAME 0
#define HEADER_CENTER 1
#define HEADER_SUM  2

void MainWindow::CreateTable()
{
    QStringList strlist;
    strlist << "Name" << "Description" << "Sum";

    QTableWidget *simple_table = ui->tableWidget;
    simple_table->setColumnCount( 3 );
    simple_table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( strlist );
    simple_table->setRowCount( 10 );
    simple_table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    simple_table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);   //Растягивать все колонки

    // модель данных стандартная, элементы по умолчанию не созданы
    QTableWidgetItem *item;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        item = new QTableWidgetItem();
        // Ограничиваем возможности первого столбца только отображением.
        // Устанавливаем только требуемые флаги.
        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
        item->setText( QString("String %1").arg(i+1));
        simple_table->setItem(i,HEADER_NAME,item);
        item = new QTableWidgetItem();
        item->setText( QString().setNum((i+1) * 10 ));
        simple_table->setItem(i,HEADER_SUM,item);
    }

    CCombo_Delegate * pCombo_Delegate = new CCombo_Delegate( simple_table );
    pCombo_Delegate->values().insert( 1, "первое значение" );
    pCombo_Delegate->values().insert( 2, "второе значение" );
    pCombo_Delegate->values().insert( 3, "и т.д." );
    simple_table->setItemDelegateForColumn( HEADER_CENTER, pCombo_Delegate );

    SpinBoxDelegate *pSpinDelegate = new SpinBoxDelegate(simple_table);
    simple_table->setItemDelegateForColumn(HEADER_SUM, pSpinDelegate);

    simple_table = ui->tableWidget_2;
    simple_table->setColumnCount( 3 );
    simple_table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( strlist );
    simple_table->setRowCount( 10 );
    simple_table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    simple_table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch); //Растягивать все колонки

}

void MainWindow::appendTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table)
{
    int rows = p_table->rowCount();
    p_table->setRowCount(rows+1);
}

void MainWindow::insertTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table)
{
    int rows = p_table->rowCount();
    int row = p_table->currentRow();
    p_table->insertRow(row);
}

void MainWindow::deleteTableRow(QTableWidget *p_table)
{
    int cur_row = p_table->currentRow();
    p_table->removeRow(cur_row);
}

void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QMenu menu(this);
    auto infoA = menu.addAction(tr("Append_Row"));
    auto infoI = menu.addAction(tr("Insert_Row"));
    auto infoD = menu.addAction(tr("Delete_Row"));
    if ((ui->tableWidget->hasFocus()))
    {
        connect(infoA, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ appendTableRow(ui->tableWidget); update(); });
        connect(infoI, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ insertTableRow(ui->tableWidget); update(); });
        connect(infoD, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ deleteTableRow(ui->tableWidget); update(); });
        menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
    }
    else if ((ui->tableWidget_2->hasFocus()))
    {
        connect(infoA, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ appendTableRow(ui->tableWidget_2); update(); });
        connect(infoI, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ insertTableRow(ui->tableWidget_2); update(); });
        connect(infoD, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){ deleteTableRow(ui->tableWidget_2); update(); });
        menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
    }
}
```

Код делегатов приводить не стану, он к этому вопросу не относится.
Что мне не нравится в этом коде, так это то, что для каждой таблицы надо отдельно создавать набор лямбда-выражений на каждый пункт контекстного меню. Попытка заменить 'ui->TableWidget' в лямбде указателем 'ptw' инициализированным так 'QTableWidget *ptw = ui->TableWidget;' , чтобы объявить лямбды только однажды приводит к ошибке. Может кто подскажет как это затруднение обойти.